# Crossfade background image using canvas on hover

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas, css-transitions

Background image transition is not supported cross-browser and to overcome this, I am trying use canvas element to draw images when the user hovers over/out of the section element. But it does not seem to be working. The images are not replaced at all.

This is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<section class="section2 animate-me" data-src="images/section2_img.png" data-src-hover="images/section2_img_hover.png">
    <canvas id="canvas2" class="background-canvas"></canvas>
        ...
        ...
        //removed for brevity
</section>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('.animate-me .animate-container').hover(function () {
            var section = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();                
            toggleCanvasImage(section.find('canvas').attr("id"), section.data("src"), section.data("src-hover"));
        }, function () {
            var section = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
            toggleCanvasImage(section.find('canvas').attr("id"), section.data("src-hover"), section.data("src"));
        });
    });

    function toggleCanvasImage(canvasId, imageFrom, imageTo) {

        canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var imageA = new Image();
        imageA.src = imageFrom;
        var imageB = new Image();
        imageB.src = imageTo;

        var i = 0.1; // global alpha      
        var runID;

        function fadeImage() {
            if (i > 1) {
                clearInterval(runID);
                return;
            }
            ctx.globalComposite = "lighter";
            ctx.globalAlpha = i;
            ctx.drawImage(imageA, 0, 0);
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - i;
            ctx.drawImage(imageB, 0, 0);
            i += 0.1;
            console.log("draw with alpha: " + i);
        }
        function run() {
            ctx.save();
            runID = setInterval(fadeImage, 100);
            ctx.restore();
        }

        run();
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.background-canvas {
   width: 1920px;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
}
```

The code seems to be executing just fine. On mouseover, mouseout events I am passing in 2 image urls for smooth transition which in turn executes the run function tasked to redraw the image.

The code is mostly picked from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xFryE/1/)

Any pointers why it's not working and fix for the same?

**UPATE**
Here's the fiddle with simplified version of code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/w4aytj95/2/

Comment: Check for this error `Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.`

Comment: I am not getting this error.

Comment: Could you please create a snippet of your code

Comment: Please see my updated question with the fiddle

Comment: I tried to figure what is the issues..one thing is, your canvas is place over the text, so no hover working. and another is image load is taking time to fire. You can find my preview here https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/bjvpOG